# How to present an action extension in an action sheet rather than full-screen modal view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios-app-extension, ios-extensions

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Action.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH13-SW3), action extensions appear in an action sheet or full-screen modal view. But for IPhone portrait orientation it is always fullscreen by default. How can I present the action extension view in an action sheet for the iPhone portrait orientation?

I have tried `setPreferredContentSize` and `NSExtensionActionWantsFullScreenPresentation`. Both seems to have no effect in iPhone portrait orientation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no way for an action extension to be non-fullscreen on iPhone.*

The alternative presentation when `NSExtensionActionWantsFullScreenPresentation` is false is equivalent to [`UIModalPresentationFormSheet`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/1621491-formsheet). Form Sheet presentation is non-fullscreen only on iPad — it's the presentation style you see for things like composing a new message in Mail, or viewing app details in the App Store. You can still choose form sheet presentation on iPhone,* but it behaves equivalent to fullscreen.

<sup>* Well, sort of. It's not actually iPhone vs iPad that makes form sheet be fullscreen, but horizontally compact vs horizontally regular [size class](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html). Which means that form sheet is non-fullscreen on iPhone 6/6s Plus in landscape orientation, but not in portrait orientation or on other iPhone models.</sup>